# Initialize Select box with loading option, then clear when model is loaded

Tags: angularjs

I have a select box, and I load the form using a JSON request on load. As angularjs may take a little time to load the data, I added a temporary option in there:

```
<option value="">Loading...</option>
```

What I want to do, is clear this once my model is loaded. What currently happens, is it just appends the list to the select box, and leaves the `Loading...` option in there as choice #0.

I believe the default behaviour is just to append, rather than replace. How would I go abouts doing this? I can't seem to find any examples around for this particular issue.

Here's a plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/zRQCPrMzvN8Rcg8ZyTu0?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty easy to do with Angular.

All you have to do is data-bind the default option to a variable and change that variable when the http call comes through. Here is a plunk demonstrating the same.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Vn4L5boLodSi6puzM6gh

Comment: Oh right. But the reason for the <option>Loading is because I don't want the select box to be blank whilst loading the list. This, although solves part of my problem, doesn't help with the other part. As the title says: Initialize select box with a loading option.

Comment: In that case you just need to do this 

<option value="" ng-bind="defaultText">Loading...</option>

Comment: That just changes it to a blank option, it doesn't remove it.